# How to display current page using PDFKit on Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, pdfkit

How to display the current PDF page when reading a PDF file using the PDFKit on swift ? That small box on the top or bottom of the page displaying “ 1 of 20 “ for example.

Comment: let total =  pdfView.document?.pageCount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current page like this:

```
let currentPageIndex = pdfDocument.index(for: pdfView.currentPage!)
```

Comment: but do you know how can i display the current page while scrolling the pdf Document ?

Comment: @HCD1407 You must use PDF delegate and a method like pageChanged(). Not really sure, Google it.